# Django ModelChoiceField and date: match = date_re.match(value)

Tags: python, django, date, django-queryset

I have a form, where with other stuff I want to save a date, which is being dynamically generated from other model, where all available dates are stored.

The problem arises when trying to save date: I am getting error "TypeError at /form/ expected string or buffer".

I can't understand way, because in "POST" i am getting string and model's object representation also is string:

My models:

```
class OrderPickUp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pick_up_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

class AvailableDates(models.Model):
    city_A = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.city_A)
```

froms.py

```
class OrderPickUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderPickUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["pick_up_date"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AvailableDates.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = OrderPickUp
        fields = ['name', 'pick_up_date']
```

views.py

```
def pick_up(request):
    form = OrderPickUpForm()
    if  request.POST:
        form = OrderPickUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {
            "title":"thanks for ordering",
            }
        else: 
            context = {
            "title":"Something missing",
            }
    else:
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

But when I am submiting the form i get error:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/marius/developer/TUTORIALS/PLAYS/testavimai/datos/views.py" in pick_up
  12.         if form.is_valid():
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  394.         self._post_clean()
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  430.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in full_clean
  1149.             self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in clean_fields
  1191.                 setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in clean
  587.         value = self.to_python(value)
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
  1274.             parsed = parse_date(value)
File "/Users/marius/.venvs/plays/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py" in parse_date
  60.     match = date_re.match(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /form/
Exception Value: expected string or buffer
```

Any ideas??

Comment: you are trying to have your `pick_up_date` field mean two things: in the `OrderPickUp` model it is defined as a `DateField` but in the `OrderPickUpForm` for that model you are trying to define it as a `ModelChoiceField`... which would mean on the model it should be a `ForeignKey` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have discrepancy in the form and model definition. You defined your `pick_up_date` in your `OrderPickUp` model as `DateField`, but in your form you make it a `ModelChoiceField`, which is used for foreign key type of fields. If what you want is to select from a list of `pick_up_date`, you should modify your model to be:

```
class OrderPickUp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pick_up_date = models.ForeighKey('AvailableDates')
```

Just a note, it's better to use singular name instead of plural, so you might want to change `AvailableDates` to `AvailableDate`.